# Design a PDA for the language L={0^n1^n | n>=1}

Tags: elementary-set-theory, context-free-grammar

Question: L={0^n1^n | n>=1}

I have found these transitions for the given language:
1)`delta(q,0,Z)=(q,0Z)
2)delta(q,0,0)=(q,00)`
The above two rules will cause one 0 to be pushed onto the stack for each 0 read from the input.

3)`delta(q,1,0)=(p,epsilon), when we see a 1 in the input go to state p and pop one 0 from the stack.`
4)`delta(p,1,0)=(p,epsilon), pop one 0 from stack, per 1 read from the input.`
5)`delta(p,epsilon,Z)=(final state, Z), now the whole input is consumed and we reach the final state and the stack is empty and we have hit the bottom of the stack. Symbol 'Z' denotes the bottom of the stack.

Please tell me whether my solution to this problem is correct? Thank You

Comment: If you’re accepting by final state, it looks fine, provided that you specify that `final state` is an accepting state.